# Finding MLE for $P[X > x]$ with $x>0$ given for exponential distribution?

Tags: probability, statistics, statistical-inference

**Problem:** Let $X_1, \ldots, X_n$ be a random sample from an exponential distribution with parameter $\theta$. Find a MLE for $P[X > x]$ with $x>0$ given (fixed).

**My attempt:** I first calculated: $$ P[X > x] = \int_x^{\infty} \theta e^{-\theta y} dy = e^{-\theta x}. $$ I also know that $$ L(\theta; \vec{x}) = \prod_{i=1}^n f(x_i; \theta) = \theta^n \exp \left(- \theta \sum_{i=1}^n x_i \right).$$ Then $$ \ln L(\theta; \vec{x}) = n \ln(\theta) - \theta \sum_{i=1}^n x_i. $$ How to proceed now? Normally when we are looking for the MLE for a parameter $\theta$, we differentiate with respect to that parameter. But now I'm asked to find the MLE for a probability. Do I just differentiate with respect to $e^{-\theta x}$?

Help is appreciated.

Comment: To estimate the MLE for the parameter $a=P(X>x)=e^{-\theta x}$, simply write down the likelihood as a function of $a$ and the sample $\vec x$. Here, considering $s=\sum\limits_kx_k$, $$L(a,\vec x)=\theta^n\exp(-\theta s)=(-\log a)^nx^{-n}a^{s/x}$$ hence $$\log L(a,\vec x)=n\log(-\log a)-n\log x+(s/x)\log a$$ and you can proceed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For any (measurable) function $g(\theta)$, $\hat{g}_n = g(\hat{\theta})$, this called the invariance property of the MLE estimator. Hence, in your case 
$$
\hat{p}_n = e^{-\hat{\theta}_n x}.
$$

Where $\hat{\theta}_n = \frac{1}{\bar{X}_n}$ is the MLE of $\theta$.

Comment: Ah I think I found the theorem you are referring to in my course notes. It goes as follows: Consider a one-to-one function $g : \theta \mapsto g(\theta)$. If $\hat{\theta}$ is a maximum likelihood estimator for $\theta$, then it can be shown that $g(\hat{\theta})$ is a maximum likelihood estimator for $g(\theta)$.  --- Is this what you are referring to?

Comment: Yes, but there is no  necessity for $g$ to be one-to-one function.See [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/80584/invariance-property-of-maximum-likelihood-estimator).